# Adding arrays together that have the same first key value

Tags: php, arrays

I have this simple array within an array like this with N number of nested arrays

```
[  
   {  
      "period":"2014-07-16",
      "test":1
   },
   {  
      "period":"2014-07-15",
      "test2":1
   },
   {  
      "period":"2014-07-16",
      "test2":47
   }
]
```

What I have been trying to do (with a number of different and equally failing ways) is to merge the ones that have the same period and if they have the same second key (in this case test2) they add the values together. If they don't, it adds that key onto the array.

```
[
   {
      "period":"2014-07-16",
      "test":1,
      "test2":48
   },
   {
      "period":"2014-07-15",
      "test2":1  
   },

]
```

My latest attempt that was the closest to what I am wanting (code below)

```
        // $datesArray is the first mentioned array of values.
        // finalArray is an empty array that I want to push the final values into.
        for ($i = 0; $i < count($datesArray) - 1; $i++) { 

            for ($j = $i; $j < count($datesArray); $j++) { 

                $key1 = array_keys($datesArray[$i]);
                $key2 = array_keys($datesArray[$j]);
                // First check to see if they have the same date, if they don't then no merging!
                if ($datesArray[$i]['period'] == $datesArray[$j]['period']) {
                    if ($j == $i) {
                        array_push($finalArray, array(
                            'period' => $datesArray[$i]['period'],
                            $key1[1] => $datesArray[$i][$key1[1]]
                        ));
                    } else {
                        if ($key1[1] == $key2[1]) {
                            array_push($finalArray, array(
                                'period' => $datesArray[$i]['period'], 
                                $key1[1] => $datesArray[$i][$key1[1]] + $datesArray[$j][$key2[1]]
                            ));
                        } else {
                            array_push($finalArray, array(
                                'period' => $datesArray[$i]['period'],
                                $key1[1] => $datesArray[$i][$key1[1]],
                                $key2[1] => $datesArray[$j][$key2[1]]   
                            ));
                        }
                    }
                }

            }
        }
```

This produced this result:

```
[
   {
      "period":"2014-07-16",
      "test":1
   },
   {
      "period":"2014-07-16",
      "test":1,
      "VeloxMorgana":47
   },
   {
      "period":"2014-07-15",
      "VeloxMorgana":1
   }
]
```

Edit: I just realized my code will not work with an N number of different keys, which I need it to. Ugh. Back to the drawing board!

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
$finalArray = array();
foreach ($datesArray as $date) { 
    $pushed = false;
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($finalArray); $i++) { 
        if($finalArray[$i]['period'] == $date['period']){
            $key = array_keys($date);
            $finalArray[$i][$key[1]] = $date[$key[1]];
            $pushed = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    if(!$pushed) {
        array_push($finalArray, $date);
    }
}
```

the `if(!$pushed)` statement will only be true the first time (because $finalArray has no elements, thus the second for-loop will not do anything) or when the 'period' value is a new one.